# SPSS v22 export to .emf causes encoding issues in the exported graphic

Tags: export, spss, .emf

I'm using SPSS for a research project and I want to export the graphs to a vector graphic format to keep them clean and zoomable. The export to .emf causes my local characters like ä,ü,ö (german localisation) to render as Ã¼ or Ã¶. In another thread I read that this is a bug of SPSS 21 so I switched to v22. Now on v22.0.0.1 I still have this issue when exporting as an emf-file. I tried using unicode as well as my country specific encoding in the settings but neither of these work and I get these strange symbols in the exported file.
Did I miss something or is there some kind of workaround for this?